# Can you force overlap to go down on an individual grid-area contenxt in a css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Essentially I have a grid view shown in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9m0p3jqb/3/

```
 <div class="container">
  <span class="idh text">Id</span>
  <div class="id">1</div>
  <span class="desch text">Desc</span>
  <div class="desc">06/11/2021;06/12/2021;06/18/2021;06/19/2021;06/27/2021;06/28/2021;07/09/2021;07/10/2021;07/16/2021;07/17/2021;07/23/2021;07/24/2021;07/30/2021;08/06/2021;08/07/2021;08/13/2021;08/14/2021;08/20/2021;08/21/2021;08/27/2021;08/28/2021;09/04/2021"</div>
  <span class="notesh text">Notes</span>
  <div class="notes">These are notes</div>
</div>

.container {
  align-items: baseline;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'id idVal'
    'desc descval'
    'notes notesVal';
  grid-template-columns: 50px 400px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 50%;
}

.idh {
  grid-area: id;
}

.id {
  grid-area: idVal;
}

.desch {
  grid-area: desc;
}

.desc {
  grid-area: descval;
  flex-grow: unset;
  background: blue;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.notesh {
  grid-area: notes;
}

.notes {
  grid-area: notesVal;
}

span {
  color: rgb(49, 71, 129);
}
```

All I want to do is ensure that any text wraps down but keeps the width I set.  I thought this would be easy to find but so far I have not seen it.  I am almost tempted to use an old school table instead of a grid but I figured someone much better than me at CSS could do this.

So in the example below the overflow would just go down and the entire second row would just enlarge down.
[image]

Comment: You should look into word-break

Comment: @ZohirSalak That did it with: 'word-wrap: break-word'.  In the class of .desc.  You can submit the answer and I can give you points if you like.